# Can Visual Studio / VSS be configured to show the name of the user that checked out the file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

There must be a way to find out who checked out the file directly in Visual Studio without having to open the VSS client and navigate to the file.

Right?

Comment: Was just discussing this the other day - would love to know a way to do this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the SourceSafe (Soure Control) toolbar to VS.  Select a file in your source tree you want to know who has it checked out and from the toolbar choose the SourceSafe Properties Icon and look at the Check Out Status Tab. :)

Comment: I should be ashamed to know this since VSS has such a bad name. :)

Comment: Also, if you are in a situation where this is occuring a lot and is making life miserable, VSS can be put into multiple checkout mode via the administration tool.  Then it acts more like SVN and most other source control systems in that files are not locked out by a single checkout and you merge work together when necessary.

Comment: If I could only convince my boneheaded coworkers that merging is not evil :) I should just turn multiple checkout on and go from there..hehe. Great answer by the way!

Answer (score 2):

When you attempt to check out a file and get the error dialog indicating that the file is already exclusively checked out, if you bring up the output dialog and switch to the source control view you should see a message indicating the user id of the user who has the file checked out.

Comment: +1 but I'll give the answer to klabranche because it requires less work once you add that "SourceSafe properties" button on your toolbar.